# Android-thread exception

Tags: android

I have a problem while executing two thread simultaneously in android.
Through one thread am handling a method which is to be excuted after certain time interval and with the other am trying to handle onClick response on several button ,but the problem is only one thread is executing i.e, the one with which am calling the method.
Kindly provide me solution.
Thanking you in anticipation.

```
Thread th=new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run(){
                try
                {
                    for (timer = 0; timer < 1000; timer++)
                    {
                        int waited = 0;
                        while(waited < splashTime)
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                          ds.open();
                                          String               quotes=ds.getRandomQuote();
                                          textView.setText(quotes);
                                          ds.close();
                                        //textView.setText(num[timer]);

                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
        };th.start 


private void quotes() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     for (timer = 0; timer < 1000; timer++)
     {
         int waited = 0;
         while(waited < splashTime)
         {
             try {
                  ds.open();
                  String quotes=ds.getRandomQuote();
                  textView.setText(quotes);
                  ds.close();


              }
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
         }
         waited+=100;
     }

}

private void getAllQuotesFromAssets() {
if(ds.getRandomQuotesList().size()==0)
{   
    new performBackgroundtask().execute();}


            }

Thread th1=new Thread()
{
  public void run()
  {  



public void myClickHandler(View view)
{


        switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.author_button:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "author",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,AuthorList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.category_button:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "category",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,CategoryList.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;


        case R.id.fev_list_button:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "fevourite",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,fev.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;


        case R.id.random_button:
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "random",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this,Random_quotes.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

};
th1.start;
   th.join;
```

Comment: Please edit to add some more context, is this code an `Activity` code? What is `ds`? And I think you should take a look at [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Your_Current_activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // your UI code here
    });
```

because [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#q=%20runOnUiThread) is method of Activity class instead of Thread